# Resque Scheduler on Heroku... Do it remotely?

Tags: ruby, heroku, scheduled-tasks, redis, resque

I'm adding [Resque-Scheduler](http://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler) in my app on Heroku

So... I need ONE alone and distinct worker acting as the scheduler and
many doing the jobs.

This is how I've done it :
I've a distinct Heroku App which does nothing but has 1 resque-scheduler worker, running 24/7, adding **Resque** tasks to the Redis DB of the "distant" **main** App.

(I do that mapping **jobs:work** task to **resque:scheduler** or **resque:work**)

Is this the best way to do it on the Heroku's platform ; or am I doing it totally wrong ?

Thanks !

EDIT: 
minimal app for scheduling on Heroku :
http://github.com/clmntlxndr/heroku-scheduler

UPDATE: With the new CEDAR stack on Heroku and Procfiles, it's possible to start a distinct task for each worker.

```
web:        bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
scheduler:  bundle exec rake resque:scheduler
worker:     bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I misread your question the first time. I missed the part where scheduler requires a separate rake task.

Yes, I think the only way to do it is to have two separate heroku apps, because heroku workers will only run `rake jobs:work` and presumably you can only map this onto one of the resque rake tasks.

You could try this:

```
desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => ["resque:work", "resque:scheduler"]
```

But I have sincere doubts about that actually working properly with how Heroku monitors worker processes and stuff. Also, double check the rake syntax there; it's just from memory. I know it's possible to specify multiple dependencies though.

Comment: Yep! The way I describe in my question is already almost working fine (I'll put it on Github soon). I was just wondering if it is good in the principle, and waiting for someone to say me "Stop ! you can assign a distinct worker on a distinct task doing that :..." :)

Comment: Yep, pretty certain there's no way to do that.